# Having internal error on 12.04 with intel video

Tags: 12.04, graphics, video, intel

I get the xserve-xorg-video-intel problem where it says I need to install it but I'm unable to find this anywhere. I do the sudu apt-get install -f but still there is nothing that changes. I have turned off the error report so at least that is not bugging out. FYI the graphics seem fine. To whom it may concern, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo apt-cache search xserver` and see what is available. You can also type `dpkg -l` to list what you have installed. See if there is a related package available that you don't have installed.